# How to find where an object is created in flex/actionscript 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In my project I have noticed 20-40% CPU time when my app is idle.
In debugger when I pause I always land on a flex.utils.Timer/tick.
This timer has 30ms delay between "ticks"

I didn't create that Timer... so this is problably a component I have added

Unfortunately it will be difficult to remove all compenents until if find the "one" ..
Yes I should have notice the CPU usage sooner !
and yes I will do that if I don't find another solution

I am of course using some components without having their sources...

My questions :
* How can I find the guilty component ?
* I tried to find it using Kap Inspector without success ...any tips for Kap inspector ?
* Is there another great tool to track object creation ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've never seriously used Flex, but doesn't it come with a profiler? You could use that.

Comment: I didn't find how track object creation but
DropShadowFilter is causing the problem !

<mx:filters> 
                <mx:DropShadowFilter 
                        angle="135" 
                        distance="5" 
                        alpha="1" 
                        blurX="30" blurY="0"/> 
                <mx:DropShadowFilter 
                        angle="45" 
                        distance="5" 
                        alpha="1" 
                        blurX="30" blurY="0"/> 
        </mx:filters>

Comment: Hi, yes ! there is a profiler in FlexBuilder !!!

Comment: Erm, no, there isn't -- not in the standard version, anyway.  Professional has a nice profiler, and there's a trial download, but the profiler is definitely not a stock feature of FlexBuilder standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your breakpoint, in the Flex Debugger perspective, find the Variables tab/view.  From there, with your breakpoint set, you should be able to see all of the variables currently in local scope (local to the timer-tick event handler, that is).  The `event` variable will contain information about the timer itself -- e.g., in event.target -- and the `this` variable will tell you where the timer handler is defined.

From there, you might be able to walk back up the stack trace, using the Debug tab/view (with your breakpoint still set), to get a sense of where the Timer object might've been instantiated.  If that doesn't work, you can download a trial of Flex Builder Professional here:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flexbuilder3

... and give the built-in profiler a try.  Hope that helps point you in a helpful direction!

Answer (score 0):

No idea about Flex, but for your CPU problems, check this out:

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/05/idle_cpu_usage.html